# How to have a question with type number input in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

Is there an easier way to specify a field that only accept numbers? The question I want to ask on my survey is `How old are you?`

The way I did it is to provide a drop-down menu by specifying all the numbers but this way seems odd to me. In my case I CANNOT USE a calendar, as this will demand the specific DOB of the participants and might concern their privacy!

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image]

---

SOLUTION:

[image: DEMO 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Short answer` as the type together with `Response validation`

[image]

You can choose either a `Number`

[image]

or a `Regular expression`

[image]

Please try the available options and see which one fits your needs.
*(If in need of further assistance please let us know)*

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Can you please be patient next time?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. It has nothing to do with patience. Newcomers are many times unaware of how the site works. Even older members tend to forget. By providing a friendly reminder we try keeping [unanswered questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) to a minimum.